# java.util.logging.Logger to print method / class name

Tags: java, logging

I am using java.util.logging.Logger

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
logger.log(Level.FINEST,"log message");
```

output is something like:

```
INFO Nov 22,2017 10:59 log message.
```

Is there a way to include class + method name in the log?

```
INFO Nov 22,2017 10:59 class name, method name , log message.
```

Comment: You have specified a log format that makes the record appear that way.  My guess is that you either added an explicit Handler or Formatter, or you set the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` property, as described in the [SimpleFormatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html).

Comment: Try initializing your logger as 
**private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName())>** . this should spit name of class in every logging event.

Comment: VGR, you are correct, i extended Formatter and is working fine now!  please post this as an answer and I will accept it,

Answer (score 1):

You can find current class name by "this.getClass()" and current method name by "MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getSimpleName()" and then add our log message. For instance:

logger.( this.getClass() + MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getSimpleName() +"log message");